# Wildlfy Schedule overlapping

Tags: scheduled-tasks, wildfly, java-ee-7

I use a scheduler in WildFly 9, with this EJBs:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
```

I get loads of these warnings:

```
2020-01-21 12:35:59,000 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 6) WFLYEJB0043: A previous execution of timer [id=3e4ec2d2-cea9-43c2-8e80-e4e66593dc31 timedObjectId=FiloJobScheduler.FiloJobScheduler.FiskaldatenScheduler auto-timer?:true persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@71518cd4 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Tue Jan 21 12:35:59 GMT+02:00 2020 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT info=null] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Jan 21 12:35:59 GMT+02:00 2020.
```

But when I measure the elapsed times, they are allways < 1 minute.
The Scheduling is:

```
@Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*/5", hour = "*", persistent = false)
```

Has anyone an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little logging would help you.  This runs every second because that's what you're telling it to do with the `second="*"` section.  If you want to only run every 5 minutes of every hour, change the schedule to:

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/5", hour="*", persistent = false)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should not copy erroneous examples from colleagues...